# Can I substitute 'came' for 'have come' in this context?

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

Today I was given a task including following sentences. I would like to know whether or not I could substitute **came** for  **have come**.

*Here is the sentence:*

> You ***came*** to the party in your own car. It is a 20 minute drive home. At the end of the party your friend asks you to drive him home but you....

We were supposed to finish the "story" . I don´t remember the end but there was something like that I can´t drive him home because (and here I am not sure what tense was used) I have drunk too much .

Then we talked about possible endings. In my opinion " You came" could be substituted for " "You have come" but I understand that the past simple tense is maybe focuisng on the moment (the beginning of the party maybe) when I arrived. Still.....would it be possible to use the present perfect in the same scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. "You have come" is possible if the party is still going, and the speaker is at it; but reads very oddly if the party has finished. "Came" is possible whether the party is continuing or not.

Answer (score 1):

"You came" is past tense. If talking about an event in the past you would say 'You came'. If using past tense, the end of your sentence "your friend asks" should be "your friend asked" to match the past tense.

"Your friend asks" is present tense and so the beginning of the sentence should be "You come to the party". If using present tense you could also say "you have come to the party".

Often imaginary scenarios are described using present tense. "Imagine the following situation, you come to a party...".